# Calculate sum of integers in ListBox ans show in Label

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, sum

I'm a beginner, so to those who answer, please specify all steps taken so i can learn from it. 
I have a WPF application in which i add clients and consumptions. I need to calculate the sum of all entered consumptions. I have following code:

```
private void btnKlantToevoegen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string klant; int consumpties, maxklantconsumpties;

        klant = txtKlantNaam.Text;
        consumpties = int.Parse(txtKlantConsumpties.Text);
        maxklantconsumpties = int.Parse(txtMaxKlantConsumpties.Text);


        if (consumpties <= maxklantconsumpties && consumpties != 0)
        {
            lbOverzicht.Items.Add($"{klant} ({consumpties})");
        }

        lblTotaalConsumpties.Content = BerekenTotaalConsumpties(consumpties).ToString();
    }

    int BerekenTotaalConsumpties (int totaalconsumpties)
    {
        totaalconsumpties = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= lbOverzicht.Items.Count; i++ )
        {
            totaalconsumpties += int.Parse(lbOverzicht.Items[i].ToString());
        }

        return totaalconsumpties;
    }
```

I calculate the total of entered 'consumpties' in the function 'int BerekenTotaalConsumpties', but i get a FormatException Error.

Answer (score 1):

I was completely unable to understand the logic of your code .. but I am sharing my answer because the issue is quite visible.

You are converting the string value to integer which can not be converted to integer.

I am explaining it step by step ..

**1.  You are adding item to the list:**

```
 if (consumpties <= maxklantconsumpties && consumpties != 0)
 {
     lbOverzicht.Items.Add($"{klant} ({consumpties})");
 }
```

Here ..lets suppose {klant} is 'XYZ' and {consumpties} is 10.. then the item which will add to the list will be .. "XYZ (10)"

**2. Now you are converting list item to integer for addition:**

```
totaalconsumpties += int.Parse(lbOverzicht.Items[i].ToString());
```

the string value "XYZ (10)" cannot be parsed to integer .. you have to track 10 separately and then perform sum operation on it.

If you can explain the logic a little .. I hope I can share a workaround with you and explain it to you.

Comment: Well basically i don't understand how to track the integer (consumpties) seperately.

Comment: I can share one method .. declare a global List<int> object .. add the (consumpties) in it ..at the time of Sum .. get the item from that list .. hope this can help

Comment: The logic of above code: user needs to enter a client and an amount of consumptions to that client. The consumptions may not exceed a set maximum. User must be able to see the total number of clients he entered and the total number of consumptions for all clients.

Comment: Not familiar with that method List<int> but will try and post back here.

Comment: I googled a bit, but still stuck. Don't see (yet) how to implement 'List<int> consumpties = new List<int>();'

Comment: I am not sure if global list will work in this case .. let me check.

Comment: I don't understand: 'lbOverzicht.Items.Add($"{klant} ({consumpties})");' here we know the integers. We want the sum of those in a label.

Comment: are you doing this for learning or you need to implement something?

Comment: because if you need to implement .. you can do something like this .. set default value 0 to the label  .. first item add .. add first consumpties to lable's value and put the new value to the lable .. Convert.ToInt32(yourlabel.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(consumpties).. .. repeat this process every time you add the item to your least box . this will show latest sum to the label

Comment: my way to learn something is to get some related samples from web .. then review their working .. this helps me a lot

Comment: I understand. But was trying to calculate total entered consumptions with a method because afterwards i will need to visualise this in a progress bar.

Comment: Anyway, if putting in method, you spoke of doing this with List<int>. Can you give example in my case?

Comment: do you have knowledge about global and local variables .. private, public, static variables? ..

Comment: I will ask to close this question as i took the wrong approach.